# Chromecast sdk for web session.queueLoad is not a function

Tags: javascript, chromecast

[Chromecast sdk](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.Session#queueLoad)

I was not able to invoke `session.queueLoad(...)`, however if I use `session.c.queueLoad(...)` it works occasionally.
I'm also able to call `session.loadMedia(...)`. 
Here's a code sample I stripped out from my site.

```js
var session = cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
      if(session)
      {
        var queueingItems = [..blahblah]
        console.log(queueingItems) //works
        queueingItems=queueingItems.map(m=>{
          var mediaInfo = new chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo(m.source, m.contentType)
          mediaInfo.metadata = new chrome.cast.media.GenericMediaMetadata();
          mediaInfo.metadata.title = m.description;
          var q = new chrome.cast.media.QueueItem(mediaInfo)
          q.autoplay=true
          return q
        })
        
        var qloadRequest=new chrome.cast.media.QueueLoadRequest(queueingItems)
        console.log(qloadRequest)

        //works
        session.c.queueLoad(qloadRequest,function(){
          console.log("loaded success")
        },()=>{})    
        
        //doesn't work
        session.queueLoad(qloadRequest,function(){
          console.log("loaded success")
        },()=>{})   
        
        //works
        session.loadMedia(qloadRequest[0],function(){
          console.log("loaded success")
        },()=>{})  
      }
```

Comment: "queueLoad(queueLoadRequest, successCallback, errorCallback)" -from docs.
log out their errors in error callback.

Comment: It doesn't event reach errorCallback, it just says it is not a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.getCurrentSession()` returns a `CastSession` object. That doesn't have the `queueLoad` method. I think you want to use [CastSession's](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/cast.framework.CastSession#getSessionObj) `getSessionObj` method as that returns a `Session` object which has `queueLoad` method.

Comment: Something to note is that the queueLoad does not return a promise like loadMedia does. Instead it accepts success and failure callback as arguments.

The signature looks like this:

queueLoad( 
request: LoadRequestData, 
successCb: function(optional), 
failCb(optional) )